# Android Socket Refused Connection

Tags: android, sockets

on my Android Phonne, I checked my Ip address is 10.0.0.8
so, I assign a socket to my phone

```
   Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.8",3200);
```

my server IP is 10.0.0.6

so I try alternative,

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.6",3200);
```

same error, connection refused.

But when I stepped into the line, it says Connection refused.  I mean, why connection refused? It's itself , no need to make a connection. All I am doing is to make a socket and there's no connection yet.

On my computer I ping both 10.0.0.6 and 10.0.0.8 and successful. Peer to Peer network is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

When you run this code, it attempts to connect to the server on a port which may or may not be accepting incoming connections.

This can be seen from the android development references:

Socket(InetAddress dstAddress, int dstPort)
Creates a new streaming socket connected to the target host specified by the parameters dstAddress and dstPort.
-http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

For examples of how to use Sockets in your Android program, I suggest looking at this site:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/